# SQL - Reusing query with different inputs - anyway to move those inputs to the beginning of the statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here's an overly-simple query:

```
SELECT
       name
       ,year

FROM
       Table1


WHERE
       name LIKE 'McMurderFace%'
       AND year < 2007
```

So say next time, you want to search for a different name & year - one would have to go down to the WHERE statement.  In a simple query like this - that's fine.  But I'm wondering about with much larger / more complex queries.

Is there a way to set variables at the beginning of the query, so that if one wanted to search for say name LIKE '%SparklesBunny' and year < 2004, they could just edit something in the beginning of the query?

e.g., this isn't how it works, but something like this:

```
Set var inputname = McMurderface
Set var inputyear = 2007

SELECT
       name
       ,year

FROM
       Table1


WHERE
       name LIKE 'var(inputname)%'
       AND year < var(inputyear)
```

Does such a thing exist?

**Edit - OK it does:**

**Edit 2 - but you have concatenate when using this for LIKE**

```
DECLARE,
       @varname AS varchar(100) =  'McMurderface'
       ,@varyear AS int = 2007

SELECT
       name
       ,year

FROM
       Table1


WHERE
       name LIKE @varname + '%'
       AND year < @varyear
```

Comment: Plenty of docs online - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187953(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: You clearly know the term "variables" so did you search for `sql server variables`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use variables like this.

```
declare @var as int = 1
select @var
```

You should be able to take it from there.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answer, which fixes the way to declare a parameter. You have to pass the parameters to `LIKE` like this:

```
..
WHERE name LIKE '%' + @inputname + '%'
  AND year LIKE '%' + @inputyear + '%';
```

Comment: Wildcards can be included in the variables, e.g. `declare @StartingWith as VarChar(10) = 'Mc%';`. Forcing the query to _always_ add a wildcard to the start of the pattern prevents the query engine from using an index lookup. (An index _scan_ is still possible.) Adding it to the end prevents a user from using `declare @EndingWith as VarChar(10) = '%ski';` when desired.